# Call $provide outside config. Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-injector

**I know that is not possible to call $provide outside the config block. Is there any trick to inject $provide to a service calling it at $provide.decorator ?**

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .config(function($provide){
    $provide.decorator('myService', function($delegate){
      //inject the $provide into myService through $delegate
      return $delegate;
    }
  })
```

Comment: and why do you need `$provide` in your service?

Comment: That is the same thing as injecting as parameter but with less abstraction.

Comment: Reuse decorator pattern implemented by angular.

Comment: @MiguelL Notice that `$provide.decorator` takes effect only if it is registered before the decorated service is instantiated (i.e. injected the first time).

Answer (score 1):

`$provide` is special because it is defined by Angular internally, it can be found by injector [among service providers](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.3/src/auto/injector.js#L623) (so it is available in `config`) but not among [service instances](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.3/src/auto/injector.js#L640).

This can be fixed easily with

```
angular.module('app', []).config(function ($provide) {
  $provide.value('$provide', $provide);
});
```

But this way the components can be defined in ill-timed manner easily as well.